# C Programming Pointers -- Why are my values changing?

Tags: c, pointers, pthreads

Whenever I do ./thread 88 90 92 I get this

4

46

56

57

54

57

46

and I'm not sure why.  It should print out the argc which should be 3 (it says 4) then print out the 3 numbers that i gave it which is 88 90 92.  Then it should print out 90 92 88.  Did i mess my pointers up?  This is my first C program that I have done by myself.  Advice is appreciated!  Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int avg;
int max = 0;
int min;
int j;


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    printf("%d\n", argc);
    j = argc;


    printf("%d\n", avg);
    printf("%d\n", max);
    printf("%d\n", min);



}
```

Comment: Are you doing your calculation is separate threads on purpose?

Comment: Yes i am doing it on purpose.

Comment: You cannot compare numbers that way, if they are given as strings. Try to convert them to numbers first, e.g.with atoi.

Comment: You've declared each of your functions as returning `void*` but, of course, none of them have `return` statements. Don't you need to return something? Turn up your compiler warning level if it didn't complain about this.

Comment: I was just using that to modify they avg, max, and min and use the main to print it out.

Comment: The compiler probably knows that pthread_exit never returns, so it doesn't complain about the enclosing function's lack of return after that point.

Comment: Actually, I'm no expert on pthreads so you do what you think is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The first element is the program name.  argc is 4, and the values you want are [1] through [3] (skip 0).

Comment: Thanks.  I changed that now i get a segmentation fault.  I'm guessing that is due to my pointers.  I'm not 100 % on pointers since i'm new so i know i probably messed something up.

Comment: To understand pointers, learn a little machine language.  See how variables can contain addresses of other things.  Draw pictures.  Keep strong type info.  Using threads or other complex stuff at the same time is not helping—work on an exercise that only works with pointers.  I got a lot out of Knuth's classic text, which uses examples in a machine-like language.